# Trouble with formulating code for correct math result

Tags: java, math

I've written a program that "buys" and "sells" bitcoin, although my buy function is giving incorrect math results.

In my program, I have $20000 (double USD) and bitcoin (which is worth $4000.

All its supposed to do is deduct how many bitcoin you are buying from your USD.

Every time I use the buy function (input 1) to buy at least 2 at a time, it works once, and then calculates incorrectly. It goes from 20000 to 12000 (correctly) and then from 12000, to -4000. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I know the answer is probably simple, but I feel like I've tried everything.

```
import java.util.*;

public class P3a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dates d = new Dates();
        String s = d.getDate();
        System.out.println("Date is" + s);
        W3 mywallet = new W3();
        Scanner myscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double buy = 0.0;
        int choice = 0;
        double bitcoin = 4000;
        double USD = 20000;
        while (choice != 5) {
            System.out.println("Welcome! Enter a command. \n"
                    + "Enter 1) Buy Bitcoin \n"
                    + "Enter 2) Sell Bitcoin  \n"
                    + "Enter 3) Print Balance \n"
                    + "Enter 4) Print History \n"
                    + "ENTER 5) Exit Program\n");
            choice = myscanner.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("How many? ");
                buy = myscanner.nextDouble();
                mywallet.add(buy);
                bitcoin = bitcoin * buy;
                USD = USD - bitcoin;
                System.out.println("you have bought:" + mywallet.numcoins);
                System.out.println(USD);
            } else if (choice == 2 && USD >= bitcoin) {
                System.out.println("How many?");  
                buy = myscanner.nextDouble();
                mywallet.subtract(buy);
                System.out.println("you have sold:" + mywallet.numcoins);
                USD = USD + bitcoin;
                System.out.println(USD);
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("Balance:" + mywallet.numcoins);
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("Print Transaction history");
            } else if (choice == 5) {
                // exit
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting the `bitcoin` variable.

On the first iteration you run:

```java
bitcoin = bitcoin * buy;
```

This will set `bitcoin` to be equal to `4000 * 2`.

On the second iteration you run the same line. This will then set `bitcoin` to be equal to `(4000 * 2) * 2`.

You need to reset the value of `bitcoin` to `4000` once you are done using it.

You can either reset the value of bitcoin at the end of the if statement:

```java
if (choice == 1) {
    System.out.println("How many? ");
    buy = myscanner.nextDouble();
    mywallet.add(buy);
    bitcoin = bitcoin * buy;
    USD = USD - bitcoin;
    System.out.println("you have bought:" + mywallet.numcoins);
    System.out.println(USD);
    bitcoin = 4000; // this line was added
} else if (choice == 2 && USD >= bitcoin) {
```

Or even better:

Create a final static variable representing the price of the bitcoin, then utilize that in calculations needing that price constant. It would look something like this:

```
public class P3a {
    private static final double BITCOIN_VALUE = 4000;

    ...
    // your other code
    ...

    buy = myscanner.nextDouble();
    mywallet.add(buy);
    bitcoin = BITCOIN_VALUE * buy;
    USD = USD - bitcoin;
    System.out.println("you have bought:" + mywallet.numcoins);

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bitcoin = bitcoin * buy;
USD = USD - bitcoin;
```

You're changing the state of the program here. After the first run, `USD` is 12000, but `bitcoin` becomes 8000. So next time you do the same thing you get the unexpected value.

Use temporary variables inside the while-loop so that the original variables are not overwritten. In fact, it'd be better to mark `bitcoin` as a `final` variable.